# Does there exist a group of even order which every element is a square?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Does there exist a group of even order which every element is a square? I know in any group of odd order every element is a square. I am not sure the case of even order. Any suggestion?

Comment: So for a finite group $G$, [$G=G^2$ if and only if $|G|$ is odd](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Odd_Order_Group_Element_is_a_Square).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple counting argument, noticing that a group of even order has an element of order 2, so that squaring cannot be a bijection - shows that you can't have every element a square.

Comment: If $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, and a generator for $C_n$ is $a_n$ we can create a chain of groups $C_2\lt C_4 \lt C_8 \dots \lt C_{2^n} \lt \dots$ where the inclusion is created by setting $a_{2^{n}}^2=a_{2^{n-1}}$. Take the union of these groups and you find that every element has even order and every element is a square.

Comment: And now we say that $\aleph_0$ is even, because $\aleph_0 = 2\cdot\aleph_0$, ...